# Python not updating variable defined as a calculation of other two variables

Tags: python

[image: Assignment]

I am doing a lambda school python pre-course and in the first assignment, I have to calculate a person's BMI. Well, I declared `w` and `h` for the weight and height of the individual and set them to some value. Then I declared

```
w=78
h =1.82
BMI = w/h**2
print(BMI)
```

Everything was fine up to this point. But the next point asks to calculate the BMI without creating the variables again, just changing their values.

I did this

```
h = 1.63
w = 59
print(BMI)
```

Does anyone know why python rescues the stored value of BMI instead of reevaluating it since I defined it as an operation?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post your code as this very difficult to follow.

Comment: You are probably "updating" the BMI within a function without `return`ing it or using `global`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did

```
BMI = w / h**2
```

then that is an expression, which is immediately evaluated and the result is assigned the name `BMI`. The relationship is *not* stored, the resulting value is.

It is quite confusing what you were supposed to achieve, perhaps using a function? That would look like:

```
def compute_bmi(w, h):
  return w / h ** 2
```

and you would use it like so:

```
>>> print(compute_bmi(80, 1.80))
24.691358024691358
```

Comment: Is there a way to store a relationship of variables without using functions?

Comment: @klithe Why would you *not* want to use functions?

Comment: There is always `eval`. But don't use that. Use a function. (Even if you don't *want* to, what you *really* don't want to is using `eval`.)

Answer (score 1):

As already explained [in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59842314/2745495), `BMI` is a variable and it does not get re-evaluated when you change the values originally used to set its value. The simplest solution here would be to put the BMI computation into a function, then just call that function every time `w` and `h` is updated.

But, if you want to make it look like the BMI value is "automatically calculated" after updating weight and height, you could also put them all in a class and then use properties to store the weight, height, and BMI values.

```py
class Health():
    def __init__(self):
        self._w = 1  # set defaults
        self._h = 1  # set defaults

    @property
    def weight(self):
        return self._w

    @weight.setter
    def weight(self, value):
        self._w = value

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._h

    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        self._h = value

    @property
    def bmi(self):
        return self._w / self._h ** 2
```

Then, use the class like this:

```py
myhealth = Health()

myhealth.weight = 78
myhealth.height = 1.82
print(myhealth.bmi)

myhealth.weight = 59
myhealth.height = 1.63
print(myhealth.bmi)
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
23.54788069073783
22.20633068613798
```

This is an overkill solution over using a simple function.
I am quite not sure why you asked [*is there a way without using functions?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842235/python-not-updating-variable-defined-as-a-calculation-of-other-two-variables/59855283#comment105819219_59842314)
(Though, this solution still uses functions.)

For more information on properties:

- From SO: [How does the @property decorator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17330160/2745495)
- From Python docs: [`property()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)

Comment: Thank you I have got much more information than asked that will serve me for future problems. The problem was with the wording of the task that made think that python could store a variable in function of other variables when that is obviously not the case I just had to rewrite everyhting again and since it was so easy I thought there was something fishy there. Appreciate the help :)